# Localizing validation messages at client side by jQuery in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, localization, jquery-validate, data-annotations

I am using jquery for client side validation together with data annotations. Everything is working fine but I would like to localize a message when a non numeric value is entered in numeric textbox. For server side validation it can be done by setting DefaultModelBinder.ResourceClassKey to resource class name and providing value for PropertyValueInvalid key.

However for client side validation asp.net mvc is using it's own resource file with key 'ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider_FieldMustBeNumeric'. The only way to solve it that I found is described at [Custom Server and Client Side Required Validator in MVC 2 using jQuery.validate](http://jwwishart.wordpress.com/2010/03/22/custom-server-and-client-side-required-validator-in-mvc-2-using-jquery-validate/). The solution does work but I was wondering if there is an easier or more correct way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit more elegant way is to rewrite `System.Web.Mvc.ClientDataTypeModelValidatorProvider` class and replace it in `ModelValidatorProviders.Providers` collection.

See section *Implicit Non-Numeric-Field problem* in  http://jwwishart.blogspot.com/2011/03/custom-server-and-client-side-required.html for more details.